# Simple Python Median Filter for time series

Tags: python, filtering, time-series, signal-processing, noise-reduction

I have a time series in a log file having the following form (timestamp, value) :

`1433787443, -60
1433787450, -65
1433787470, -57
1433787483, -70`

Is there any available python code/library that takes as input the log file and a window size, apply a median filter to the time series to remove noise and outliers, and outputs the filtered signal to a new file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Load the data using any method you prefer. I see that your file can be treated as csv format, therefore you could use `numpy.genfromtxt('file.csv', delimiter=',')` function.
2. Use the scipy function for median filtering: `scipy.signal.medfilt(data, window_len)`. Keep in mind that window length must be odd number.
3. Save the results to a file. You can do it for example by using the `numpy.savetxt('out.csv', data, delimiter=',')` function.